# Reactjs, GraphQL and Redux - How to Handle blog's pagination automatically?

Tags: reactjs, redux, pagination, graphql, blogs

I'm working currently on my first blog with `Reactjs`, `GraphQL` and `Redux`. I wonder how to handle the blog's posts pagination.

I have thought to send the blogpost in my database then refech it with the activation of the route. Then create a mechanism leading to create a new page each time 8 blogposts have been fetch to the current page. But I feel like this is a very approximative way to handle the blog post pagination automatically. Before passing to action I would discuss with the community about the best way to create automatic's blog post pagination.

*Below, an illustration of pagination in Stackoverflow :*

[image]

any hint would be great,
Thanks